Display Gitlab merge request title in slack
I integrated our gitlab repo with slack but that only works for automatic notifications. What I would like is that anytime someone manually posts a link to a merge request in slack it should display the title and maybe description. The same as when we post a link to a JIRA in slack
I know this is doable with GitHub slack integration, I’m trying to see if it’s doable with Gitlab
Edit: I just double checked, even the automatic notifications only displays a link to the merge request, there’s no details in slack
